# Access 2010 Form Close button

Tags: ms-access, button, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if there is a way to know if the windows form button is clicked. I know of the CloseButton property but it seems you can only enable or disable it. I have forms closing when the user navigates through my app but would like to close the database only if the windows close button is pushed. So i need the close event to distinguish when I close it via programming or the user close via windows button. I could use a boolean check but was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Also if there's a way to completely remove the button and not just have it greyed out looking ugly that would be amazing but I read that this may be unwise since this is a windows setting.

Comment: What do you mean by "the windows form button"?

Comment: @HansUp Hi Hans,  sorry I have the forms set to pop and I meant to say, is there a way for me to check if the close button is clicked. I would really like to remove it entirely and use my own. But as I mentioned I heard that was not advisable.

Comment: If I understand now, I would go with what you consider the inelegant way.  Your custom close button sets a variable to `True`.  At `Form_Unload`, check that variable and `Cancel` the unload if it's not `True`.  Then the form can only be closed by your custom close button.  Even attempting to close Access itself will not allow the form to close ... and will abort Access shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code module for a form which includes a command button named `cmdClose`.  The form can not be closed except by the `cmdClose` click event.  Even attempting to close Access itself will not allow the form to close ... and will abort Access shutdown.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    AllowClose "close"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If AllowClose = False Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "close aborted"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function AllowClose(Optional ByVal pClose As String) As Boolean
    Static blnClosedFromCode As Boolean
    If pClose = "close" Then
        blnClosedFromCode = True
    End If
    AllowClose = blnClosedFromCode
End Function
```

Comment: @HelloWorld  I realize that's what you don't want.  However, I offer it in case someone else may find it useful.  I don't consider it all that inelegant.  It's effective and I think fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

In short I don't think their is a way, but the code HansUp provided is a work around.  I disable the close button at top to ensure data is saved.